# Dihedral group actions on Spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

As an outsider of algebraic topology, I would like to consult your guidance to understand finite group actions over spheres. I do not imagine how a group acts on a sphere, in particular why a group acts freely on some spheres. I've read that $D_{2n}$ acts non-freely on any sphere. If someone could explain the action of $D_{2n}$ on $S^1$ and give some book examples to study group actions on spheres for those who are new to these things?

Comment: One very interesting result is that any finite group acting freely on the sphere has periodic cohomology. To see this, take a CW structure compatible with the action, then the cellular chain complex gives the start of a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$, but since the top homology of the sphere is $\mathbb{Z}$ we can add another copy of the cellular chain complex there, ad infinitum. So since the cochain complex is periodic, the cohomology is periodic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dihedral group acts on $S^1$ by rotations (by $\frac{2m\pi }{n})$ and reflections about the symmetry axes of the regular $n$-gon. The action is not free in general because rotating a point on $S^1$ by some angle can have the same effect as a reflecting it about one of the axes which tells us that the action is not free. This can also be seen from the fact that the reflections have fixed points.

Comment: What sources would you recommend so that I can understand more about this topic?

Comment: @Cadenza Any book on abstract algebra (I recommend Pinter) will probably talk about group actions, I'm not sure exactly what more you're looking for though. I would also greatly appreciate it if you accept my answer if it was satisfactory :)